# How to supress the output of .sql script when placed inside bash script

Tags: sql, oracle, bash, unix, spool

Below is my simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /app/oracle/client11_2/
connect <<EOF
@/app/oracle/client11_2/testquery.sql
exit;
EOF
```

Note: testquery.sql contains some "SELECT" queries and also i have used spool to store the content of the queries.

But, when i execute the bash script on the terminal, it produces lot of unwanted output like below:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0
Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

How to avoid this output..!? I do not want this to be printed on the output screen when i execute the bash script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the here doc (`<<`) snippet as:

```
connect <<EOF >/dev/null
@/app/oracle/client11_2/testquery.sql
exit;
EOF
```

this sends the STDOUT of the here doc to `/dev/null`.

---

You can also do the output redirection at run time, sending the whole STDOUT of the script to `/dev/null` e.g.:

```
./script.sh >/dev/null
```

again this sends the whole STDOUT of the script to `/dev/null` (YMMV).

Answer (score 2):

You can suppress the SQL*Plus header messages by using the -s flag

```
sqlplus -s
```

That said, your snippet shows a connect but not the sqlplus invocation itself. Not sure where that is being hidden.